# How to add 64 bit support to android app?For publishing

Tags: android

I tries to publish a app.But i got error

```
This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement error fix
```

I searched google find by adding below code it will make app 64 bit

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
        }
```

But still i got that error i have only 3 architecture in my app

[image]

How to fix that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Some hit and trail method.I Solve this problem.

I am using a third party dependency which don't support x86_64 architecture.So i just build my app for armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a.

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a'
        }
```

Now the further question is how much it effect the total number of device support

```
ARMv7: 98.1%

Intel x86: 1.7%
```

source:https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186334/what-percentage-of-android-devices-runs-on-x86-architecture

so if you face same problem than its not a big issue to leave x86 architecture